Problemas con pdf, esta vacío
Otra vez yo jaja, mi tema aquí es que mi pdf sale vacío, ya se descarga y se envía bien, incluso los bytes que pesa son "congruentes" con la información que tiene, pero cuando lo abro esta vacío, solo es una hoja en blanco.
$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','Letter');
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->Image('../img/spf.png' , 8 ,8, 80 , 22,'png');
    $pdf->Ln(35);

    $pdf->Cell(196,8,utf8_decode('Archivo solicitado: '.$doc),1,1);
    $pdf->Cell(98,8,utf8_decode('Fecha de préstamo: '.$fechaD),1);
    $pdf->Cell(98,8,utf8_decode('Hora de préstamo: '.$horaD),1,1);
    $pdf->Cell(196,8,utf8_decode('Fecha de devolución: '.$fechaDv),1,1);
    $pdf->Ln();

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
    $pdf->Cell(196,5,utf8_decode('*Este documento avala el trámite de préstamo, por lo que debera presentarlo en cuanto se le entregue el Documento Oficial, y así'),0,1,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(196,5,utf8_decode('mismo cuando se devuelva.'),0,1,'C');
    $pdf->Ln(90);

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
    $pdf->Cell(196,5,utf8_decode('Recibí Documento Oficial original.'),0,1,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(196,5,utf8_decode($nombreP),0,1,'C');

    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    /*header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="valePrestamo.pdf"');*/
    $pdf->Output();

Esta es la salida del pdf del servidor.
$.ajax({
                url: 'base/prestarD.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $("#fprestamo").serialize(),
            }).done(function(respD){
                if(respD.trim().length > 0){
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'success',
                        title: 'Trámite de préstamo exitoso',
                        text: 'En un momento se descargará tu vale de préstamo',
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonText: "Aceptar",
                        confirmButtonColor: "#4169E1",
                        showCloseButton: false,
                    }).then(()=>{
                        console.log('ENTRE AL THEN');
                        const blob = new Blob([respD], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        const link = document.createElement('a');
                        link.href = url;
                        link.download = "valePrestamo.pdf";
                        document.body.appendChild(link);
                        link.click();
                        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                    });
                }else{
                    console.error('La respuesta del servidor está vacía');
                }

y finalmente la del ajax, espero puedan ayudarme y disculpen las molestias, no sé exactamente donde esta el error.

tienes que hacer debug, 1. evalua que los datos son recogidos por ajascript y que son gestionados por php justo hasta antes de emitir el pdf de descarga, desde ese punto si no se ve el contenido... comienza a tirar un paso atras y evaluar si el contenido esta siendo procesado correctamente antes de pasarlo al pdf ...asi sucesivamente ... y de paso recomendacion, incluye en tus post todo lo que haces por tu cuenta para hacer el debug
